# TextView in a custom view is not switching text color in night mode

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

Using:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
```

If I have a layout xml file in a fragment/activity with a TextView:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If I go between light/dark mode the text color switches appropriately.

However if I create a custom view:

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) { ... }
```

And that view contains the same textview, the text color does not change in night mode.

I initialize the view from a fragment:

```
new MyView(this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
```

I have also tried to directly apply the base theme:

```
new MyView(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), null, R.id.AppTheme);
```

In addition for some strange reason I can work around this issue by creating my own text colors in the appropriate light/dark folders and that picks up the change between light/dark:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/my_text_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was passing the wrong context.

When creating the view:

```
new MyView(this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
```

Should be:

```
new MyView(this.getActivity());
```